# when system run out of memory, the mmap memory is swapped to swap area or the mapping file?

Tags: linux, kernel, swap, mmap

I mmap a very large file (10g), if the system is going to run out of memory, the mmap memory is swapped to swap area or the mapping file?  My os is redhat. thanks

Another question is when the 60% memory is used, the system start to swap. Is it normal? How can I configure when os can do swapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mmap memory should be swapped back to the mapping file, i think.

/proc/sys/vm/swappiness is one of the tuneables that let you decide, when the system should swap and when not. Default is 60, on a recent kernel 0 will disable swapping, 1 will minimize it.

Comment: if I disable swapping, Will the mmap memory be swapped back to the mapping file when system run out of memory? I doubt whether disabling swapping can also disable the mmap memory swapping.

Comment: I believe it will kill the process that's OOMing when swappiness=0